# Group by month name from sqlite in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, sqlite

In my app, I have employee report stored in sqlite database. In that "reportTable", I have one column named "MonthName" in which values are like

```
MAY16
JUN16
JUL16
```

which are in TEXT, not in DATE format in sqlite table. And there are multiple dates in column "start_date" and values are like

```
start_date      MonthName
01MAY16         MAY16
03MAY16         MAY16
04MAY16         MAY16
```

Now I need the list of months by year wise in sectioned tableview, as section title is year like 2016 and rows are like month name which are present in table as May, jun, July, etc.

I can get distinct month name by query

```
SELECT DISTINCT MonthName FROM reportTable
```

Then fetch data by MonthName but it is not sorted by month and it will be problem in future when there are multiple years of data added. So help me to sort out this problem to sort and show data properly by year and month wise.